# Material-ui DataGrid and Infinite Scroll

Tags: datagrid, material-ui, infinite-scroll

I'm currently using [material-ui data grid](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/) component and find it excellent.

However, for a current feature I'm working on I need to have infinite scroll support within the DataGrid. Has anyone done this previously using [material-ui data grid](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/)?

Doesn't seem like its supported out of the box reading the docs. I did come across the [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui-x/issues/404) which has some suggestions in the comments.

Keen for any tips on how to use infinite scroll with [material-ui data grid](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, easiest way is to use commercial version.
Find it here on infinite Loading section:
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-updates/
Props name is onRowsScrollEnd. This can fire a function to fetch more data.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the apiRef prop for DataGrid to a reference returned by `useGridApiRef` from `@mui/x-data-grid`, you can subscribe to events generated by the grid through that reference. There's a `scrollPositionChange` event you can subscribe to, which you can use to manually calculate the position of scroll and use that to determine when to fetch the next page.

There are methods to get the currently loaded number of rows and the scroll position as well.

Relevant code in Typescript below:

```js
const gridApiRef = useGridApiRef();
const scrollMonitor = React.useRef<Function>();

const handleScroll = React.useCallback(() => {
  if (gridApiRef.current?.instanceId) {
    const currentRowCount = gridApiRef.current.getRowsCount();
    const scrollPosition = gridApiRef.current.getScrollPosition();

    // fetch next page when appropriate
  }
}, [gridApiRef.current?.instanceId]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  if (gridApiRef.current?.instanceId) {
    // You can call scrollMonitor.current() to unsubscribe from the event
    scrollMonitor.current = gridApiRef.current.subscribeEvent("scrollPositionChange", (event) => {
      handleScroll();
    }
  });
}, [gridApiRef.current?.instanceId]);

return (<DataGrid apiRef={gridApiRef} ...props />);
```

Comment: I get an error 'gridApiRef.current.subscribeEvent is not a function' with the above code. 
Is this a pro only feature?